# Simple arithmetic expression doesn't compute in PL/pgSQL 9.3.5

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, parentheses, integer-division

I'm writing a user defined function and have had a lot of trouble doing simple arithmetic:

```
...
DECLARE
    alpha numeric;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'alpha: %', alpha; --alpha is NULL here
    RAISE NOTICE 'period: %', period; --period is an integer function param, it's 10
    alpha := 2/(period + 1);
    RAISE NOTICE 'alpha: %', alpha; --alpha is zero (!) here
    ...
END;
```

But if I calculate alpha in two steps, it works correctly:

```
...
DECLARE
    alpha numeric;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'period: %', period; --period is 10
    alpha := period + 1; --alpha is 11 here
    alpha := 2/alpha; --alpha is 0.1818...
    ...
END;
```

What's up with this?  Is alpha being converted to an integer in the first expression and rounded to zero?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that Postgres does integer division.  So, just add a decimal point:

```
alpha := 2.0/(period + 1);
```

Comment: That did it, thanks.  But I think that's very bad behavior on Pg's part.
I guess it makes crazy sense:

2/(integer 11) = 0 in the first part but
2/(numeric 11) = .1818 in the second part

Thanks again.

Comment: @Bandersnatch - This behave is required by ANSI/SQL - it is not PostgreSQL community design.